# VueJS and ESlint (prettier) parsing error "adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing parent tag"

Tags: vue.js, jsx, eslint, prettier

I've got a problem with my linter/prettier in VueJS. In every .vue file there is a parsing error (showing up at the `<script>` or `<style>` tag after the `<template> ... </template>`)

> error  Parsing error: Unexpected token <. Remember, adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing parent tag  prettier/prettier

I tried configuring the .eslintrc but the error is still showing up

```
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution')

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript',
    '@vue/eslint-config-prettier',
  ],
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
  },
}
```

Hope someone has an idea, cause it's driving me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `extends: [ 'vue', 'standard' ]` to the .eslintrc so it now looks like this

```
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution')

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { es6: true, node: true },
  extends: [
    'vue',
    'standard',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript',
    '@vue/eslint-config-prettier',
  ],
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
  },
}
```